# Using pyodbc in multi processing code

Tags: python, sql, database, multiprocessing, pyodbc

I am using `pyodbc` to build an application which get access to and manipulate `SQL Server 2008 R2` in a multi-process method.

I firstly designed an `DataEngine` class as follows:

```
class DataEngine:
    def __init__(self, serverName, databaseName):
        self.serverName = serverName
        self.databaseName = databaseName
        self.cn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server="+ serverName + ";database=" + databaseName + ";trusted_connection=true") 
        self.cursor = self.cn.cursor()
```

Then a `DataMapper` class:

```
class DataMapper:
    def __init__(self, dataEngine):
        self.dataEngine = dataEngine    
        self.cursor = dataEngine.get_cursor()
```

And I have defined a function which calls a `.exe` file with arguments:

```
def func(dataEngine, dataMapper, buildRunId, queueNumber, ServerName, DatabaseName, ExecutableFilePath, DLLFilePath):
    os.system(ExecutableFilePath + " " + str(inputRowId) + " " + str(ServerName) + " " + str(DatabaseName) +" " + DLLFilePath)
```

Then the function `func` has been wrapped into four separate processes:

```
queue_0 = Process(target = func, args = (dataEngine, dataMapper, buildRunId, 0, ServerName, DatabaseName))
queue_1 = Process(target = func, args = (dataEngine, dataMapper, buildRunId, 1, ServerName, DatabaseName))
queue_2 = Process(target = func, args = (dataEngine, dataMapper, buildRunId, 2, ServerName, DatabaseName))
queue_3 = Process(target = func, args = (dataEngine, dataMapper, buildRunId, 3, ServerName, DatabaseName))

queue_0.start()
queue_1.start()
queue_2.start()
queue_3.start()

queue_0.join()
queue_1.join()
queue_2.join()
queue_3.join()
```

However, when the above code is running, I've got following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 347, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.__new__(pyodbc.Cursor) is not safe, use pyodbc.Cursor.__new__()
Exception AttributeError: "DataEngine instance has no attribute 'cursor'" in <bound method DataEngine.__del__ of <dataengine.DataEngine instance at 0x000000000451FC48>> ignored
```

May I know how to deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need make separate DB connections for each `multiprocessing.Process` instance. The connection and cursor objects you're storing in each `DataEngine` instance are not picklable, so you can't send them between processes. The easiest thing to do would be to call a function that creates the `dataEngine` instance in the child process, and then calls `MatlabBuildIndex`:

```
def create_conn_and_call_buildindex(run_id, x, server_name, database_name):
    data_engine = DataEngine(server_name, database_name)
    data_mapper = DataMapper(data_engine)
    MatlabBuildIndex(data_engine, data_mapper, run_id, x, server_name, database_name)

...

queue_0 = Process(target=create_conn_and_call_buildindex, args = (buildRunId, 0, ServerName, DatabaseName))
...
```

Comment: This requires establishing a new connection each time you invoke this, though. If you are making hundreds of calls for a given tuple of connections, this can be grossly inefficient.